# Is it possible to use local and nonlocal forces simultaneously using bge?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, physics

I'm working on a space simulator and I am currently using the .applyForce() method to move objects. Is it possible to set both a local force (thust) and a global force (3d gravity) to act on an object at the same time? If so, is there a built in function for converting the orientation of a given force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple applyForce() calls per frame, some local, some global and blender works everything out - summing them together to apply a correct total amount of force in the correct direction.

Example:

```
obj = cont.owner
obj.applyForce([0, 0, -9.8], False)  # Global gravity
obj.applyForce([0, 10, 0], True) # Accelearte locally
```

Or you can do the coordinate conversions manually using the worldOrientation matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Just discovered this accidentally when searching for a work around. Found that while thrusting, the psuedo-gravity  I was using was somehow still fully active. This was unexpected, but extremely relieving to find out.